# jQuery surrounded elements are not working inside div loaded via jQuery-AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#content').on('click', '.pgr a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#view').fadeOut(500, function(){
            $(this).load(link + ' #view', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(500);

            });
        });
    });
});
```

I am using the above code at my site `http://saveongolf.net/store/category/golf-clubs-all-/` to make pagination with ajax.

The problem is that after loading of next page there is a button "Add to wish" which is not working, and also buy button attached with a JavaScript redirection which is not working after jQuery load.

Comment: Are you sure that the loaded html elements don't have IDs that might conflict with e IDs in your original document ?

Comment: Thanks for for the question.. But i am not sure what you mean. Even when we load new html into #view div then how there will be conflict? Further Please check my site and see what happen. I am not very good in jquery / javascript please

Comment: Try moving the `$('#view').fadeOut(500, function(){..` out of the click event

Comment: @ling.s Sorry not understand what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading of next page you have to attach events on non-working (in your case) buttons, to make them work again.

Attach your events again:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#content').on('click', '.pgr a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#view').fadeOut(500, function(){
            $(this).load(link + ' #view', function() {
// HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE
                $(this).fadeIn(500);

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Crone, Can you skype me at umershaikh79 ??

Comment: @MohammadUmer I have added you. Reply.